# ¿Como cerrar con logout?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que al cerrar sesión con route(logout) y el usuario presione el botón de atras no se devuelva y se redireccione al login?

Nota:Estoy trabajando con oauth en laravel 5.5

Comment: ¿Cuál es el comportamiento deseado entonces?

Comment: Yo lo logre primeramente con js evitando la acción de back cuando estoy en la página de login. Y del lado del servidor con un middleware que no cachearan las respuestas

Comment: El problema que cuando le doy atras y refresco la pagina se va al login ,pareciera que si entra al middleware sino que se hace refrescando la pagina

Answer (score 2):

Intenta poner esto en tu página de login antes de la etiqueta de cierre del body

```
<script>
    var url = document.URL;
    history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
        history.pushState(null, null, url);
    });
</script>
```

Lo que consigues con este código es que al presionar el botón de atras no tenga el comportamiento por defecto sino que sobreescribes las direcciones a donde deberia haber ido y pones la actual, osea la de login.

Answer (score 0):

¿Acaso no lo hace Laravel por defecto con un middleware?

Nunca me he encontrado con dicho problema, siempre utilizo un middleware como este para dichas rutas "protegidas":

```
if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
    } else {
        return redirect()->guest('entrar');
    }
}
```

Comment: El problema que cuando le doy atras y refresco la pagina se va al login ,pareciera que si entra al middleware sino que se hace refrescando la pagina